# Goldbach Conjecture algorithm returning one incorrect tuple each time

Tags: python, math, python-3.4

I created a function to find all combinations of prime numbers that would add up to a given number.  It is working fabulously, other than the second tuple I return is always off.  The way the code is structured it will always return both variations of a given tuple, so for example (5, 13) and (13, 5), but this incorrect tuple is always alone.

```
def goldbach_conj(number):
    prime_tup_list = []
    x, y = 0, 0
    result = 0
    if not number % 2:
        prime_list = list_of_primes(number)
        # while result != number:
        for i in range(len(prime_list)):
            x = prime_list[i]
            if result == number:
                prime_tup_list.append((x, y))
            for j in range(len(prime_list)):
                y = prime_list[j]
                result = x + y
                print("Adding {} and {}.".format(x, y))
                print("Result is {}".format(result))
                if result == number:
                    prime_tup_list.append((x, y))
    return prime_tup_list
```

If I enter 56 as my number I get this output:

```
[(3, 53), (5, 53), (13, 43), (19, 37), (37, 19), (43, 13), (53, 3)]
```

For 36 I get:

```
[(5, 31), (7, 31), (7, 29), (13, 23), (17, 19), (19, 17), (23, 13), (29, 7), (31, 5)]
```

Comment: The code wont run for the number `3`

Comment: @TheBrofessor [Goldbach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) is only for even numbers that are greater than `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition directly inside the first `for` loop seems to be the one causing the issue -

```
if result == number:
    prime_tup_list.append((x, y))
```

When you find a `result` that is equal to the number inside the second for loop, you add that to the `prime_tup_list` , but then if that was the last prime number in the list, the result is not changed and we exit out of the second `for` loop (with still the same `result`) and in the next iteration in first `for` loop, you take the next `x` value, but before you calculate `result` again, you check if `result` is equal to `number` , if it is you append `x` (new `x` , not the one used to calculate `result`) and `y` to the list.

You can remove that `if` condition altogether, not sure why it is there.

**EDIT**:

Code -

```
def goldbach_conj(number):
    prime_tup_list = []
    x, y = 0, 0
    result = 0
    if not number % 2:
        prime_list = list_of_primes(number)
        # while result != number:
        for i in range(len(prime_list)):
            x = prime_list[i] #if below here is removed.
            for j in range(len(prime_list)):
                y = prime_list[j]
                result = x + y
                print("Adding {} and {}.".format(x, y))
                print("Result is {}".format(result))
                if result == number:
                    prime_tup_list.append((x, y))
    return prime_tup_list
```

Comment: Which if can be removed?

Comment: Please check the edited code, you should also read the answer thoroughly to understand what went wrong, and where.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  When I responded I didn't see the edit yet:)  I see now that I was appending the next x with the old y regardless of the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can also edit the range on the second `for` loop, to avoid duplicates!

```
def g(number):
    prime_tup_list = []
    x, y = 0, 0
    result = 0
    if not number % 2:
        prime_list = list_of_primes(number)
        for i in range(len(prime_list)):
            x = prime_list[i]
            for j in range(i, len(prime_list)):
                y = prime_list[j]
                result = x + y
                print("Adding {} and {}.".format(x, y))
                print("Result is {}".format(result))
                if result == number:
                    prime_tup_list.append((x, y))
    return prime_tup_list
```

Output:

For 56 and 36, respectively

`[(3, 53), (13, 43), (19, 37)]`

`[(5, 31), (7, 29), (13, 23), (17, 19)]`

Comment: Awesome!  I'm a little confused as to exactly why it does, but it does.  Edit:  Figured it out:)  It is preventing the algorithm from going back and looking at numbers lower than the number currently being compared.